# How to modify a property after animating it in Unity3D?

Tags: unity, animation

I animate localPosition. The animation works well, but after, I can't change a value of localPosition in editor or code. I want to change a value after the animation completes, not at the same time.

I use Animator with AnimationClipPlayable. I create Animator in editor and the rest in code (AnimationClip, AnimationClipPlayable, AnimationCurve).

The animation animates a property from one position to another. It finishes, I don't do anything to stop the animation.

Let me know, if you need a code example or video presentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: Use `Animator.Stop()`.

It happens, because Animator still holds a property, i. e. the animation is still animating the property and hence you can't modify it. The solution is to count time and when it is right time (when the animation completes), execute `Animator.Stop()`. For example, If you animate `gameObject`, you should execute `gameObject.GetComponent<Animator>().Stop();`.

Answer (score 0):

You should avoid modification of the same variable in animation and code.

However there are two workarounds for the case:

1. Wrap your object in an empty object and then change properties of an inner object in animation and change properties of outer object by code.
2. Use LateUpdate to change a property in code which is already changed in animation. LateUpdate is executed after everything included animators.

### edit

make sure no other state in animator has the `write defaults` flag on. If any has, then by entering that state **all animated properties animator-wide** will be reset to their default values.

Comment: Feels like my question is not plain enough. I don't want to modify the property and animate it at the same time. I need to do it after the animation completes. The problem is any modification has no effect after animation.

Comment: changing one value at the same time is not possible in unity (in this case option1 still is valid), but if you are changing one value in code and animation (in different frames) you should consider either options. I suggest trying LateUpdate first.

Comment: You don't understand. 1. I can change a property. 2. Animation starts and completes. 3. I can't change a property. First, verify that you understand the question. I think it is because the animation still holds a property and I need to free it, may be by stopping the animation. Can you say how to do it?

Comment: I added a note to my answer.

Comment: I found a solution. I needed to stop animation by Animator.Stop(). I will post the solution later.